# How to create survey form using Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to shiny and programming, I m trying to create survey form in shiny app and i found all what i am looking for in Dean Attali example Google mimicking form and i found two versions but both gave different error message.

the first one 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daattali/shiny-server/master/mimic-google-form/app.R

here is the error 
   Error: do not know how to convert 'data$timestamp' to class “POSIXct”

the second one message 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daattali/shiny-server/5ef197b233e0940fb1e5248e063ac0e7d55f02e6/mimic-google-form/app.R

and the error message
Error: cannot open the connection

how can fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this URL works fine
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daattali/shiny-server/5ef197b233e0940fb1e5248e063ac0e7d55f02e6/mimic-google-form/app.R 
just add folder and name it "responses" to save csv file in